# How to pull SQL report where info meets date range criteria?

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL. I'm trying to pull a report with the selected columns but only those where the "datecreated" is on or after 03/01/2016 and "datefirstship" is on or before 03/15/2016...this is what I thought it will work...

```
SELECT num,customerpo,shiptoname,datecreated,datefirstship,note
FROM SO
WHERE datecreated >= 2016/03/01 AND datefirstship <= 2016/03/15
```

...but I get this error message...

```
ERROR #50805215
Query failed to execute. GDS Exception. 335544334. conversion error from string "672"
```

Comment: What's the data type of your DateCreated and DateFirstShip fields?

Comment: You're accidentally doing division in your dates.  Make sure you convert those strings to dates appropriately for your database engine. 2016 / 3 / 1 = 672.

Comment: ok..that's where the 672 is coming from....make sense. The date is shown as Mar 1, 2015. In previous error messages I got it said that the data type is TIMESTAMP

Comment: ok..that's where the 672 is coming from....make sense. The date shows 2016-03-21 00:00:00 0. In previous error messages I got it said that the data type is TIMESTAMP. Please disregard the previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by putting single quotes around the dates you specify.